# Ошибка при попытке найти cssSelector в вебдрайвере на селениуме

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit

http://prntscr.com/gl4pv4 есть такая форма на сайте. Она загружается динамически, после того как нажимается кнопка "Войти".

Вебдрайвер загружает страницу, жмет войти и после это выводит ошибку, когда пытается найти cssSelector поля логина.
WebElement loginField = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.r-form__input-element [name='login']")); - на этой строчке ошибка
Вот код:

```
package ru.babyblog;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CreatePostJournal {
WebDriver webDriver;

public boolean CreatePost(By locator) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriver.get("https://www.babyblog.ru/");
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("enter")).click();

   //тут все кликнулось ок
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   // тут жду пока откроется форма
    WebElement loginField = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.r-form__input-element [name='login']"));
   //Вот тут ошибка
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    loginField.clear();
    loginField.sendKeys("login@hi2.in");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement passwordField = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.r-form__input-element [name= 'password']"));
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    passwordField.clear();
    passwordField.sendKeys("1111");
    WebElement enterField = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.r-btn.r-btn__green.r-btn__fill"));
    enterField.click();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    List<WebElement> list = webDriver.findElements(locator);
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(list.size() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }else {
        return list.get(0).isDisplayed();
    }
    //  TODO: logic
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут `..element [n..` пробела не должно быть:

`input.r-form__input-element[name='login']
input.r-form__input-element[name='password']`

Comment: Спасибо! Блин точно)

Comment: @Артур, если ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела поста)